# Google analytics track jquery open

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

We are relaunching our company website and want to move away from inhouse analytics which are clunky and wasteful and better use our google analytics.

We have a page where we list job ads, clicking on a job title opens the job description below the title. At present we use php to track these opens and then feed each click into our database.

How can we do the same with google analytics?

Our current code is fairly standard:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#linkbox').hide();
  $('span.linka').toggle(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#linkbox' + id).show(500);
    $.post('clickrecorder.php', {"productID": encodeURIComponent(id)} );
  }, function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#linkbox' + id).hide(500);
  });
});
```

Clickrecorder.php literally increments the number in the database by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can track the ad view as a Google Analytics Event with the following:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'job ad', 'view', id]);
```

See [Event Tracking Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) for more details about Events.